# In my wordpress woo commerce order process email the currency symbol is changed by "??"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a live website and the problem I'm facing that in customer processing order email that currency symbol is changing by "??". Any possible Solutions

I've updated the woo-commerce plugin plus I have deactivated other plugins and also try changing the currency as well but still, I'm facing the same issue.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'my_order_details');
function my_order_details($order){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($order);
    echo "</pre>";}
```

The code I have put to print an array but in that array, I'm getting the issue the currency symbol is changing by ??.

Comment: Hi, try to re-set the currency simbols in woocommerce options and re-save: WooCommerce > Settings > General > Currency Options

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I have tried that already it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You can try to set the currency simbol programmatically: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-a-currency-symbol/

Comment: Dear I'm able to change the currency from the woo commerce settings but it doesn't matter whatever currency I choose it is showing ?? in place of currency symbol and it is only appearing in the email template.